# How to prevent automatic decryption using Nautilus/Nemo

Tags: nautilus, encryption

I have installed seahorse-nautilus, which allows me to encrypt files from within Nautilus (and, I note, Nemo).  But when I click on the encrypted file, it is automatically decrypted -- I am not asked for the passphrase.  This is true even after I have logged out and logged back in.  Is there any way to prevent this behaviour -- to require passphrase entry prior to decryption?

Comment: It is automatically decrypted only because YOU are logged in, and your key (in Seahorse) matches the encryption key. It won't automatically decrypt for anybody else in the universe, nor on any other machine in the universe (unless you added your key to it). Try it: Login as a different user, and see if it decrypts. Send it to a friend and see if it decrypts.. Create an account for you on the friend's machine and see if it decrypts.

Comment: You are correct; I have tried the scenarios you mention.  Yet still I would prefer not to have this behaviour.  Is there any way to prevent it?

Comment: One way: Choose an encryption key that isn't already in Seahorse. (You will probably want to write it down somewhere)

Comment: You can use the command line to encrypt the file(s). I can  provide an answer if you like.